How to check module settings and project settings？
IDEA show Following modules override project settings: ...

But I don't know which setting is different. How should I find the difference?
And How to view project settings and module settings?
I just set pom.xml
<properties>
  <kotlin.version>1.9.23</kotlin.version>
</properties>


Does this help? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-modules.html
